# PWA application builded through com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.LauncherActivity how to intercept URL

Tags: android, url, progressive-web-apps, launcheractivity

We have built PWA application through com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.LauncherActivity we have one specific requirement where we want to intercept URL loading in the activity.
We are not able to find any method by which we can intercept the URL.

Can you please help with this?